# How to know if a object inside a map has a value

Tags: javascript

I need to know if connection status !== null:

```
this.filters = new Map([
            ['destinationGeoId', null],
            ['locationGeoId', null],
            ['nationalityId', null],
            ['travelType', null],
            ['connectionStatus', null]
          ])
```

If I do console.log of filters I get this.

```
Map(5) {"destinationGeoId" => null, "locationGeoId" => null, "nationalityId" => null, "travelType" => null, "connectionStatus" => null}
size
:
(...)
__proto__
:
Map
[[Entries]]
:
Array(5)
0
:
{"destinationGeoId" => null}
1
:
{"locationGeoId" => null}
2
:
{"nationalityId" => null}
3
:
{"travelType" => null}
4
:
{"connectionStatus" => null}
length
:
5
```

I can't use hasOwnProperty. I can use `this.filters.values('connectionStatus')` but that's only give me true if the key exists, but I want the value.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has) api?

Comment: You only need to check for `null` value?

Comment: yes! only null value. I need to show a div if connectionStatus !== null. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, create a function which evaluates if a key has value.

This is just a function which compares the value of specific key.

```js
var filters = new Map([
  ['destinationGeoId', null],
  ['locationGeoId', null],
  ['nationalityId', null],
  ['travelType', null],
  ['connectionStatus', null]
]);

var hasValue = function(key) {
  return filters.get(key) != null;
};

console.log(hasValue('connectionStatus'));
```

See? the evaluation returns `false`, because `connectionStatus` is `null`.

As [Sterling Archer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/774078/sterling-archer) suggests, you can use [`Map.prototype.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) function to get the value of a specific key.

Comment: You should use the designated Map methods for this. `const hasValue = (key) => filters.has(key);` (and then `get`)

Comment: @SterlingArcher from the documentation: *The has() method returns a boolean indicating whether an element with the specified key exists or not.*, so, what you're indicating is not the case.

Comment: I hit enter too early sorry, edited in that you also need get. Or just use `get`, `has` might be overhead here like `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @halfer the problem with my answers is the last part *Hope it helps!*?

Comment: @halfer I got it, from this moment I will avoid that :-)

Comment: Great, thanks. [See also this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/472495).

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
this.filters.get('connectionStatus') !== null
```